# Statically created dates are not equal?

Tags: java, date

I'm testing the equality of dates that I create using constants and for some reason the tests are all failing.

```
public static Date date(int year, int month, int date, int hour, int minute) {
    Calendar working = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    working.set(year, month, date, hour, minute, 1);
    return working.getTime();
}
```

If I create that with the same year, month, date, hour etc then I expect it to be equal. Except that it inconsistantly isn't. I use this function in two different classes and the objects aren't equal - except only *sometimes*.

What's the issue? The epoch it gives me is occasionally 1 second behind the other and I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: how do you make the compare? can you give the code where test fails?

Comment: How do you make the compare ?

Comment: Dates won't be equal if they differ on miliseconds, if you compare them with milisecond precision.

Comment: Why don't you create your own comparison method? What kind of precision do you want?

Comment: I actually just want second precision, but I'm not going to reinvent the wheel when JodaTime works.

Goddammit Java, why aren't you easy to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getTime is millisecond precision, you are only setting to second precision. So when you compare the Dates using the `.equals()` method it will return false.

Stop using the abomination of the java date time api and use [jodatime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().secOfDay().roundFloorCopy();
dateTime.equals(myOtherDateTimeCreatedSameway);
```

Or if you are just worried about date, not time, use LocalDate.

Comment: You've explained the problem, but have not shown a solution. Can you please post code to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The old calendar-API is undoubtedly horrible in general but I show a possible solution which suppresses the millisecond part generated in constructor. This will work as long as you don't change the timezone. So sometimes the Calendar-API is underestimated while JodaTime is often overestimated.

```
public static Date date(int year, int month, int date, int hour, int minute) {
    // current time in system timezone
    GregorianCalendar working = new GregorianCalendar();

    // assuming you rather want second set to zero
    working.set(year, month, date, hour, minute, 0); 

    // no millisecond part
    working.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return working.getTime();
}
```